# How to test a decorater usage in typescript?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, decorator

Suppose there is a property decorator and a class uses that decorator on its certain properties.

```ts
function foo(options?: any) {
    return function (target: any, prop: string) {
        // some magic
    }
}

class Bar {
    @foo({ opt1: true }) zoo = 123
}
```

Suppose that I have covered `foo`'s logic in my unit tests and now am willing to write a test ensures that

**`Bar` class has used `foo` decorator on its property `zoo` with option `{ opt1: true }`**

How this test should be written ?

P.S.
I'm using [jest](https://jestjs.io) along with [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) and open to any other test frameworks if neccessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112921/unit-testing-typescript-decorators probably the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

Decorators are meant to be used directly thus cannot be mocked by normal means.
This might be a legit case to use `jest` bypass mock.

However, IMO, the objective of your test is misplaced.
You should not test the fact that it has been called with `{ opt1: true }`, you should test the **behavior** of using such decorator, if possible.

Testing it has been called with `{ opt1: true }` is the same as you want to test your `findLCD(a: number, b: number)` to make sure it has called `Math.abs(a)`.

You should focus on the behavior (that `findLCD(a, b)` give you the correct result), instead of how the code does it.

The means, if your decorator `@foo` does something that is measurable, test against that instead.

For example, if `@foo` write some log entry, find a way to test the log entry is written, instead of `@foo` has been called in certain way.

Comment: Thx! I was also thinking that I should test the behavior instead of implementation. But doing so would be undesirable. My decorators are some validators (required, minLength, etc.) which decorates certain member variables and would affect some computed variable to indicate whether all fields are meet their constraints. Testing this kinda behavior is very tedious. Just imagine that there are 10 classes with `@required` applied to it's memeber. That would results in 10xN almost-identical tests which are actually testing the behavior of `@required` and which has already been tested on its own.

Comment: I would still say that's what you should be testing against.

You can always refactor your code to test exactly that whild condensing the test code to mostly a one-liner.